# How do I create Python Code for Custom Dates in Zapier?

Tags: python, datetime, zapier

I have a zap that will send out calendar invites from Google Calendar. The dates are every other Tuesday starting 6/15/2021. The problem is - how do I tell Zapier via Python code when to start the calendar invites based on when someone starts my specific program?

Whole Zap: I assign a client a tag in Kartra. Then that tag triggers Zapier to send the calendar invites for the every-other-Tuesday call that started on 6/15/2021.

If I have someone start on 6/30 - how does Zapier know the next call date will be 7/13?

Answer (score 0):

1, example using the python code in zapier: [Python code examples in Zaps](https://zapier.com/help/create/code-webhooks/python-code-examples-in-zaps)

2, the fake code flow:

```
1, start_day = datetime.date.today() # get the date of the start
2, end_period_day = start_day + 20 # the dates are every other Tuesday starting from the start_day must be in 20 days if I was understanding you
3, end_day_of_week = end_period_day.weekday() # get the day of week on end_period_day, Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6
4, invites_day = end_period_day - ( (end_day_of_week - 1 >= 0) ? (end_day_of_week - 1) : 6 )
```

Comment: Thank you for the zapier documentation. I read through that extensively but was unable to determine what to do exactly.
As for your #2 - thank you. I'll use that and update parts as needed to see if that helps. Yes, you understood me correctly. The dates are every other Tuesday. There would only be 14 days in between though...

Comment: @Mandy Welcome, I thought that it didn't count the Tuesday on this week so using 20 days in between, I see.

Comment: I tried to copy&paste your info above changing the 20 to 14... that is not working. Is there something more I should be doing? I've put a listing out on Fiverr, but so far no luck.

Comment: @Mandy could you post your mainly code and error log by update your question ?